# Proving Brouwer's fixed point theorem using fundamental groups

Tags: homotopy-theory, fixed-point-theorems, fundamental-groups, spheres, fixed-points

I am writing my bachelor thesis on the fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ and homotopy theory.
Now I was wondering if it is possible to prove Brouwer's fixed point Theorem in arbitrary dimensions using only $\pi_1$ and no higher homotopy groups.
Since $\pi_1(S^n) = 0$ for $n \geq 2$ I don't seem to get a contradiction to having a retract $S^{n -1} \to D^n$ for $n \geq 3$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your question yourself. From the perspective of $\pi_1$ the spaces $\Bbb S^n$ and $\Bbb D^n$ with $n\geq 2$ are the same, so you cannot distinguish them with it. In particular you cannot construct a contradiction to the existence of a retraction.

Comment: Yes I suspected that this proof won't work. My question was more if there is another known argument using fundamental groups, not necessarily using retracts. Maybe some trick that could involve gluing, construction from CW-Complexes, etc...

Comment: Besides using the identification $\pi_n(\Bbb S^n)\cong\pi_1(\Omega^{n-1}\Bbb S^n)$ and somehow proving $\pi_n(\Bbb S^n) \cong \Bbb Z$ (which you kind of prohibited) I cannot think of or recall any proof along the lines you want. But I like the question :)